# Adding a UIScrollView to an existing view with lots of objects... how to easily make whole view scrollable?

Tags: ios, xcode, uiscrollview

I made an app that has a lot of content on its view (images, buttons, text labels, etc.) and is optimized for the iPhone 5 display. However, the part of the view that is missing when viewed on an iPhone 4 screen is just additional settings, and is perfectly acceptable to be hidden until scrolled to.

So, how do I made my entire view scrollable for iPhone 4 users? I tried just dragging and dropping a UIScrollVIew object over the top of the whole view, but it doesn't add scrolling capability.

I have worked with UIScrollView before, but it was always something I added to the view before anything else, and don't know how to go about adding it to my view now that there are already bunches of objects. Hopefully there is some easy solution that doesn't require manually addig every object as a subView, etc.

Thanks for the suggestions!

Comment: I'm surprised I don't see anyone else with the same question... Isn't it very hard making your iPhone 5 apps backwards compatible without completely ruining the layout and formatting, etc? How do people get around this??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know how your views are created, but the easiest thing would be to change the class of the main view from `UIView` to `UIScrollView`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried that just now, but all of the graphics get completely rearranged and everything is just a mess. How can I lock everything in place at the full iphone 5 640x1136 resolution and just have it scroll up and down if running on an iPhone 4?

Comment: I'm not sure why the layout would change. If you have a complicated layout, you should do it in Interface Builder. If you want the scroll view to scroll, you'll have to set its content size property.

Answer (score 3):

From the InterfaceBuilder you can select all your content views (images, buttons, text labels, etc.) and then select Editor > Embed in > ScrollView.

[image]

This will create a UIScrollView containing al the views selected.

**WARNING:** you will lose all constraints between these subviews and the superview or the layout margin. Relative constraints (from subview to subview) will remain.

This approach is very useful when you wan to make only some content scrollable.

Comment: It does work in terms of embedding all the elements inside the scroll view without messing up with their position, however no scrolling occurs. All the outlets were reconnected but nothing... Cleaning the build, restarting Xcode does not make any difference.